# Buffer (tampon) Page between two php pages

Tags: php, html, redirect

So I need a Buffer (Tampon) page between two pages. The first page contains an form that redirects you to a second page that sends out an email then redirects you back to the first page. I do have a Buffer page between them but it does not do what is supposed to do. I need to redirect to the buffer page as soon as I hit the POST button from the first page in order to disable it's functionality. So when I hit the button I want to be redirected to the buffer page witch will say Processing Request and then redirect to the second page. At the moment it does that but the buffer page is not displayed.

First page

```
<form method="POST" action="buffer.php">
<input text id='met' />
<input text id='myval' />
</form>
```

Buffer page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
Wait for redirect
</body>
<?php
$method=$_POST['met']; 
$value=$_POST['myval'];
header('location:2ndpage.php?met='.$method.'&myval='.$value.'');
exit;
?>
</html>
```

Second Page

```
<?php
$method=$_GET['met']; 
$value=$_GET['myval'];
mail('Send mail based on method and value');
header('location:2ndpage.php');
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use AJAX and display a message instead of going back and forth between pages?

Comment: I have on the same page multiple forms that do different things, and to separate the functionalists I used more pages that return different error messages.

Comment: But you could do the same with Ajax create multiple responses and display them on screen. That would save you the trouble of doing this unhandy thing with buffer pages. And keeps your code nice and clean.

Comment: I don't really have the time to learn what Ajax is, the due date is very close and I needed this improvisation just as a quick fix.